# iOS struct with NSArrays

Tags: ios

I have four pieces of data I always want to keep together: 2 NSArrays and 2 ints. I thought a struct might be a good idea, but I get the "ARC does not allow objects in structs" error. What would be the best way to encapsulate the data? Using an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a class with 4 properties. This allows for future growth by adding standard methods like `isEqual:` and making it work with `NSCoding`, etc. You can also add convenience constructors and other helpful methods as needed.

Comment: 1) Should this be a new, separate class or included as part of an existing one that uses it? 2) I only need one set of data as I just update it accordingly. Is a singleton pattern okay to use for this?

Comment: Create a separate class if it makes sense for your needs. This makes it easy to reuse. Using a singleton should only be used if you are 100% sure your whole app should only ever access a single instance of this class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange", nil];
NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pine",@"pinnacle", nil];
NSInteger val1 = 1;
NSInteger val2 = 2;

NSMutableDictionary *dictTest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictTest setObject:arr1 forKey:@"arr1"];
[dictTest setObject:arr2 forKey:@"arr2"];
[dictTest setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:val1] forKey:@"val1"];
[dictTest setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:val2] forKey:@"val2"];
```

Comment: Use modern Objective-C. `NSArray1 *arr1 = @[ @"apple", @"orange"];`. Then `NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"arr1" : arr1, @"arr2" : arr2, @"val1" : @(val1), @"val2" : @(val2) };`.